# Grails deployment problem with babel asset pipeline

Tags: tomcat, grails, ecmascript-6, asset-pipeline, babeljs

I have es6 javascript in the grails 3 projects which I am trying to convert to old-style javascript.

I added the following lines to `build.gradle`:

```
babel: [
   enabled: true,
   processJsFiles: true,
   options: [
       blacklist: ['useStrict'],
       loose: 'all',
       modules: 'amd',
       moduleIds: true
   ]
]

compile 'net.errbuddy.plugins:babel-asset-pipeline:2.0.6'

dependencies {
    classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
    classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.15.1"
}
```

It runs in development mode but when I deploy this war file on the tomcat server, it throws below error recorded in catalina.out in the logs directory.

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: babel/asset/pipeline/ApplicationLoader, method: super$2$configure signature: (Lorg/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder;)Lorg/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder;) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
```

Does anybody know anything about this error?

Comment: same issue here on grails 4 and tomcat 8

Comment: Hey Matthias so actually specifying the location node exec helped me to solve this error. I actually also check the location of webpack server and started it along with grails developement server. Changing babel configoptions to this helped.DO try

Comment: `configOptions = [
               babel: [
                       enabled: true,
                       processor: 'webpack',
                       processJsFiles: false,
                       nodeExec: "/usr/local/bin/node"


               ]
       ]`